# Keras ImageDataGenerator apply_transform() method shifts the image in opposite direction

Tags: python, keras, generator

When I try to implement Keras ImageDataGenerator `apply_transform` method to shift the image in the horizontal direction, the image is translated in the opposite direction.

I've seen its [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py) but not sure why implementation is like this. Below is the code

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
translate = datagen.apply_transform(x=img, transform_parameters={'ty':20})
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try -20 instead of 20

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
translate = datagen.apply_transform(x=img, transform_parameters={'ty':-20})
```

Comment: Thanks! but I am trying to find out the reason why they choose a negative value for translation in the positive direction. Any thoughts?